# Does the order of Git merging matter?

Tags: git, git-merge

Suppose I have two branches, `A` and `B`.  Do the following properties hold?

- Merging `A` into `B` conflicts if and only if merging `B` into `A` conflicts.
- The contents of my files after merging `A` into `B` is the same as the contents of my files after merging `B` into `A`.

Comment: Assuming there are no conflicts, the *content* of the merge is the same.

Comment: @Maroun That is my hunch as well, but is that actually documented somewhere? Or, does it logically follow from the known properties of the merging algorithms?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[cmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49716037/1256452) is correct, with caveats.  Let's start by noting these items / assumptions:

- There is always a single merge base commit.  Let's call this commit *B*, for base.
- The other two inputs are also single commits.  Let's call them *L* for left / local (`--ours`) and *R* for right / remote (`--theirs`).

The first assumption is not necessarily true.  If there are multiple merge base candidates, it is up to the *merge strategy* to do something about this.  The two standard two-head merge strategies are `recursive` and `resolve`.  The `resolve` strategy simply picks one at (apparent) random.  The `recursive` strategy merges the merge bases two at a time, and then uses the resulting commit as the merge base.  The one chosen by `resolve` *can* be affected by the order of arguments to `git merge-base` and hence to `git merge`, so that's one caveat right there.  Because the recursive strategy *can* do more than one merge, there's a second caveat here that is difficult to describe yet, but it applies only if there are *more than two* merge bases.

The second assumption is much more true, but note that the merge code *can* run on a partially-modified work-tree.  In this case all bets are off, since the work-tree does not match either *L* or *R*.  A standard `git merge` will tell you that you must commit first, though, so normally this is not a problem.

#### Merge strategies matter

We already noted the issue with multiple merge bases.  We're assuming a two-head merge as well.

Octopus merges can deal with multiple heads.  This also change the merge base computation, but in general octopus merge won't work with cases that have complicated merge issues and will just refuse to run where the order might matter.  I would not push hard on it though; this is another case where the symmetry rule is likely to fail.

The `-s ours` merge strategy completely ignores all other commits so merge order is obviously crucial here: the result is always *L*.  (I am fairly sure that `-s ours` does not even bother computing a merge base *B*.)

You can write your own strategy and do whatever you want.  Here, you can make the order matter, as it does with `-s ours`.

#### High level merging (with one merge base): file name changes

Git now computes, in effect, two change-sets from these three snapshots:

- *L - B*, or `git diff --find-renames B L`
- *R - B*, or `git diff --find-renames B R`

The rename detectors here are independent—by this I mean neither affects the other; both use the same *rules* though.  The main issue here is that it's possible for the same file in *B* to be detected as renamed in *both* change-sets, in which case we get what I call a *high level conflict,* specifically a rename/rename conflict.  (We can also get high level conflicts with rename/delete and several other cases.)  For a rename/rename conflict, the *final* name that Git chooses is the name in *L*, not the name in *R*.  So here, the order matters in terms of final *file name*.  This does not affect the work-tree merged *content*.

#### Low level merging

At this point we should take a small tour of Git's internals.  We have now paired up files in *B*-vs-*L* and in *B*-vs-*R*, i.e., we know which files are "the same" files in each of the three commits.  However, the way Git stores files and commits is interesting.  From a logical point of view, Git *has no deltas:* each commit is a complete snapshot of all files.  Each *file*, however, is just a pair of entities: a path name *P* and a hash ID *H*.

In other words, at this point, there is no need to walk through all the commits leading from *B* to either *L* or *R*.  We know that we have some file *F*, identified by up to three separate path names (and as noted above, Git will use the *L* path in most cases, but use the *R* path if there is only one rename in the *B*-vs-*R* side of the merge).  The complete contents of all three files are available by direct lookup: *H<sub>B</sub>* represents the base file content, *H<sub>L</sub>* represents the left-side file, and *H<sub>R</sub>* represents the right-side file.

Two files match exactly if and only if their hashes match.<sup>1</sup>  So at this point Git just compares the hash IDs.  If all three match, the merged file is the same as the left and right and base files: there is no work.  If L and R match, the merged file is the L or R content; the base is irrelevant as both sides made the same change.  If B matches either L or R but not the other, the merged file is the non-matching hash.  Git only has to do the low-level merge if there is a *potential* for a low-level merge conflict.

So *now*, Git extracts the three contents and does the merge.  This works on a line-by-line basis (with lines grouped together when multiple adjacent lines are changed):

- If both left and right sides touched only *different* source lines, Git will take both changes.  This is clearly symmetric.
- If left and right touched *the same* source lines, Git will check whether the change itself is also the same.  If so, Git will take one copy of the change.  This, too, is clearly symmetric.
- If left and right touched the same lines, but made different changes, Git will declare a merge conflict.  The work-tree content will depend on the order of the changes, since the work-tree content has `<<<<<<< HEAD ... ||||||| base ... ======= ... other >>>>>>>` markers (the `base` section is optional, appearing if you choose `diff3` style).

The definition of *the same lines* is a little tricky.  This does depend on the diff algorithm (which you may select), since some sections of some files may repeat.  However, Git always uses a single algorithm for computing both L and R, so the *order* does not matter here.

---

<sup>1</sup>To put this another way, if you manage to produce a Doppelgänger file—one that [has different content from, but the same *hash* as, some existing file](https://shattered.it/), Git simply refuses to put that file into the repository.  The shattered.it PDF is not such a file, because Git prefixes the file's data with the word `blob` and the size of the file, but the principle applies.  [Note that putting such a file into SVN breaks SVN—well, sort of](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/subversion-sha1-collision-problem-statement-prevention-remediation-options).

---

#### -X options are obviously asymmetric

You can override merge conflict complaints using `-X ours` or `-X theirs`.  These direct Git to resolve conflicts in favor of the *L* or *R* change respectively.

#### Merging makes a *merge commit*, which affects merge base computation

This symmetry principle, even with the above caveats, is fine for a *single* merge.  But once you have made a merge, the *next* merge you run will use the modified commit graph to compute the new merge base.  If you have two merges that you intend to do, and you do them as:

```
git merge one    (and fix conflicts and commit if needed)
git merge two    (fix conflicts and commit if needed)
```

then even if everything is symmetric in each merge, that does not mean that you will necessarily get the same *result* as if you run:

```
git merge two
git merge one
```

Whichever merge runs first, you get a *merge commit*, and the second merge now finds a different merge base.

This is particularly important if you do have conflicts that you must fix before finishing whichever merge goes first, since that also affects the *L* input to the second `git merge` command.  It will use the first merge's snapshot as *L*, and the new (maybe different) merge base as *B*, for two of its three inputs.

This is why I mentioned that `-s recursive` has potential order differences when working with multiple merge bases.  Suppose there are three merge bases.  Git will merge the *first two* (in whatever order they pop out of the merge base computation), *commit the result* (even if there are merge conflicts—it just commits the conflicts in this case), and then merge that commit with the third commit and commit the result.  The final commit here is then the input *B*.  Only if *all* parts of this process are symmetric will that final *B* result be order-insensitive.  *Most* merges are symmetric, but we saw all the caveats above.

Comment: Thanks for supplementing my very high-level, imprecise answer with this low-level, precise, technical detail answer :-)

Answer (score 15):

I would go as far as to say that if your two properties are not met, then you have found a bug in `git merge`.

Rationale: Merging concurrently in all directions is the very purpose for which `git` has been built. That is why `git` has been using 3-way merges from the off: It's the only way to provide correct merge results. This 3-way merge is symmetric from a mathematic point of view, it basically computes a state `R = (A - B) + (C - B) + B` based on a base commit `B` from the diverged states `A` and `C`. *The only difference that comes from merging order should be the order of the parents of the merge commit.*

---

Edit: If you are interested in more details, [torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49721107/2445184) is what you are looking for. It gives you all the technicalities about the different merge strategies, and points out where my answer is imprecise due to being written at a very high abstraction level.

Comment: The question is whether it applying `(C - B)` followed by `(A - B)` to `B` is guaranteed to yield the same results as doing it in the reverse order, for arbitrarily complex merges (e.g. involving rename detection and similar advanced featured). Since git has no [formal theory of patches](ftp://ftp.math.ucla.edu/pub/camreport/cam09-83.pdf), the claim that all merges are symmetrical and that anything else is a bug should be backed by documentation.

Comment: @user4815162342: Git does not apply the changes in that order. Specifically, GIt starts from the three blob hashes (base, left, right): if B=L or B=R, take the one that's not equal. Only if all three are unequal do we get a merge—and then we get a *merge conflict* for any case where there could be any asymmetry. As for renames, the rename detector runs *before* merging, on the tree-results of the two diffs, and these are also unaffected by order. However, all of this holds only for *one* merge.

Comment: There is some more to this, so I will write up a real answer.

Comment: @torek Thanks for clarifying the renames. *Only if all three are unequal do we get a merge—and then we get a merge conflict for any case where there could be any asymmetry* - is this documented somewhere? Or are you saying that that is a fundamental property of `patch` which is historically understood and doesn't need specific documentation? I am genuinely curious about this; the concept of "applying a patch" has never seemed precisely defined (in git), and given that patch is allowed to interpret its input with some "fuzziness", it's not entirely clear what they are.

Comment: @user4815162342: Merge doesn't actually apply patches. See my answer (more or less done I think now). For the actual code that merges files, see https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/xdiff/xmerge.c (and everything in `xdiff/` really).

Comment: @torek Fascinating answer, thanks for taking the time to write it up.

Answer (score 1):

Merge conflicts happen when two people change the same lines in the same file, or if one person decided to delete it while the other person decided to modify it.

So basically,

- If there are conflicts when you try to merge B to A,
  there will be conflicts when you try to merge A to B.
- The result of merging A into B and B into A has to be the same(if there are no conflicts).

The question is purely logical. So if anyone thinks my logical answer is wrong or needs improvement, feel free to correct me or edit this.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know by heart the algorythms but I believe it is very much "yes" for both questions. If you have found a counterexample it would be very nice to see it. So far I am not aware of any.

I'd check some ambigous cases, for example if a section of file was duplicated next to it by one person and modified by another. Which of the copies are to change? As there is no single correct answer, it could depend on minor reasons like order of parents.

Answer (score 0):

Consider A to be the master branch and B to be the sub branch.

1. Now create a readme.txt file and add some content i.e, "change 1" stage it and commit it.
2. Now create another sub branch B, make some changes to readme.txt i,e append "change 2" to readme.txt and commit it.
3. Switch back to Master branch A, now you'll not see any changes made by sub branch B. To reflect the same changes made by B merge from the master branch i.e, from B into A
4. Once your are there in master branch A, append "change 3" to readme.txt file and commit it.
5. Now checkout to sub branch B, append "change 4" to readme.txt and commit the changes that you have made
6. Once when you were there in sub branch B, merging the master branch A into sub branch B causes Merge Conflicts

*Since you'll not see the text "change 3" in readme.txt file from sub branch B, and you are not appending the text "change 4" to readme.txt file. Instead you are overwriting the readme.txt i.e, by merging the contents of the text readme.txt having "change 3" to the text "change 4"*

From the above example both the properties holds good.