# Merge old branch into new or new into old

Tags: git, git-merge

My git repository currently has two feature branches created from the master branch. Let's call the two feature branches A and B. A was created 4 commits before B was created. Currently A and B have almost no overlap with only one small merge conflict.

Because of business schedules, I'm not allowed to merge A and B into master for another 45 days. As I continue to work, I'm now having some trouble remembering which branch contains which changes, and I would like to merge the two branches into one. What are the advantages and disadvantages of merging A into B (the older into the newer)?

```
git checkout B
git merge A
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of merging B into A (the newer into the older)?

```
git checkout A
git merge B
```

Comment: You may wish to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715421/does-the-order-of-git-merging-matter).

Comment: They don't have "advantage and disadvantages". They are two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either approach would produce the same result from a code perspective, as long as you make the same merge-conflict resolution decisions when merging.

From a perspective of reading the git history, it makes more sense to merge the older branch into the newer, since you can more easily track the dates of commits, but that is just a user preference.

I would suggest, since management is in your way, to merge these two branches into a separate temporary third branch.

```sh
git checkout A # can checkout B as well
git checkout -b temporary-C-branch
git merge B # or A if you checked out B first. Also think about using --no-ff if you want a merge commit as well
```

That way you don't have to mess-up A and B when merging.

Answer (score 0):

> the advantages and disadvantages

None. Merging A into B and merging B into A are simply two things — two different things. There is not a choice between them; they are not mutually exclusive (you can do both, and people often do), and one is not "better" than the other. You do the one that you do because that is what you want to do.

The topological difference is simply in what happens to the respective branches and which one is the "first parent".

- If you are on A and you merge B into A, then B stops before the merge commit; the merge commit is made on A, *you* are still on A, and the previous commit on A is the merge commit's first parent (and B is its second parent).
- If you are on B and you merge A into B, then it's exactly the reverse: A stops before the merge commit; the merge commit is made on B, *you* are still on B, and the previous commit on B is the merge commit's first parent (and A is its second parent).

There is also, of course, a difference between who is `--ours` and who is `--theirs`. That matters in case you pick some merge strategy that uses that distinction in case of a conflict. However, all other things being equal, the content of the merge commit is exactly the same regardless of which "way" the merge is performed.