# Can a merge conflict occur in Git depending on the order of the branches merged?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, merge-conflict-resolution

Let's assume we have four Git branches: `main`, `feature-a`, `feature-b` and `feature-c` (where the feature branches are all originating from `main`). I know that `feature-a` and `feature-b` contain conflicting changes and so I create a new branch called `feature-ab` (that originates from `feature-a`) and merge `feature-b` into it (including resolving the occurring merge conflict).

Now I want to merge `feature-ab` and `feature-c` back into `main` and wonder which order I should merge them in. My question is: Is a situation possible where merging `feature-ab` first (and `feature-c` second) would **not** create a merge conflict while merging `feature-c` first (and `feature-ab` second) would create a merge conflict?

A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715421/does-the-order-of-git-merging-matter) already clarifies that the result of:

```
git merge one    (and fix conflicts and commit if needed)
git merge two    (fix conflicts and commit if needed)
```

is not necessarily the same as:

```
git merge two
git merge one
```

So I would assume that it is possible to create a situation where the different merge bases would lead to a merge conflict in one case while being conflict-free in the other case. Is that correct and if so, how could I construct such a situation?